# Is there a ${\bf 0'}$-computable linear order with "all intervals wild"?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, linear-orders

Say that a linear order $L$ is a **thicket** iff $L$ is infinite, and for all elements $a,b,c_1,...,c_n\in L$ with $a<_Lb$ and $[a,b]_L$ infinite the following are equivalent:

- $\{a,b\}\subseteq \bigcup_{1\le i\le n}\mathsf{Haus}_L(c_i)$, where "$\mathsf{Haus}_L(x)$" is the *Hausdorff block* of $x$ in $L$, that is, the set of all $y\in L$ such that the interval between $x$ and $y$ is finite.
- $[a,b]_L$ is Medvedev-reducible$^1$ to $(L;c_1,...,c_n)$.

Basically, a thicket is a linear order which is as non-homogeneous as possible, in a computability-theoretic sense. It is not hard to prove that thickets exist; roughly speaking, there is a particular forcing whose sufficiently-generic filters yield maps $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that the sum $\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Q}}\underline{f(x)}$ is a thicket, where $\underline{k}$ is the linear order with $k$ elements.

This construction works below ${\bf 0'''}$, and (I'm pretty sure) below ${\bf 0''}$ as well with a bit more care. However, beyond that things aren't clear to me:

> **Question 1**: Is there a ${\bf 0'}$-computable thicket?

More generally, I'd be interested in any information about the degrees which do compute thickets - including *lower* bounds on such (I don't have any nontrivial ones right now). I think a natural "bookend" to Question 1 is the following:

> **Question 2**: Is there a [PA degree](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-51/issue-1/%CE%A0-1-0-Classes-Peano-Arithmetic-Randomness-and-Computable-Domination/10.1215/00294527-2010-009.full) (ideally, one below ${\bf 0'}$) which does *not* compute a thicket?

---

$^1$The definition of Medvedev(/"strong") reducibility is a bit technical, but roughly $\mathcal{X}\le_s\mathcal{Y}$ iff there is a single Turing functional which when given a copy of $\mathcal{Y}$ will produce a copy of $\mathcal{X}$. If we rearrange quantifiers so that the Turing functional depends on the copy of $\mathcal{Y}$ we get Muchnik(/"weak") reducibility, which is much better understood. To the best of my knowledge we currently only know four ways to produce a linear order $L$ with an endpointed interval $J$ not Medvedev-reducible to $L$:

- Thickets provide the "extremal" example.
- "Sufficiently $\omega_1$-like" ordinals are Medvedev-incomparable, via a short (but not *quite* trivial) elementary submodel argument, and we can get a snappier argument if we assume large cardinals.
- For $r:\omega\rightarrow\{1,2\}$ let $A_r=\sum_{i\in\omega}\mathbb{Z}+\underline{r(i)}$. Then if $(r_z)_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a "mutually sufficiently Cohen generic" sequence of functions $\omega\rightarrow\{1,2\}$, each individual $A_{r_z}$ is Medvedev-incomparable with $\sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}\underline{3}+A_{r_z}+
  \underline{3}$. Thickets are of course more extreme, but this type of construction gives *scattered* examples. (Of course there is a lot of flexibility in the details here.)
- *(Knight/A. Soskova)* For $x\subseteq\omega$ let $\mathsf{Shuff}^+(x)$ be the shuffle sum of $x\cup\{\omega\}$; this is the unique-up-to-isomorphism countable linear order in which $(i)$ each Hausdorff block is isomorphic to either $\omega$ or some element of $x$, and $(ii)$ each such type of Hausdorff block occurs within every infinite endpointed interval. Now let $x$ be non-$\Sigma^0_3$; the linear orders $\mathsf{Shuff}^+(x)+\underline{1}+\mathsf{Shuff}^+(\omega)$ and $\mathsf{Shuff}^+(x)+\underline{1}$ can be shown to be Medvdedev-incomparable by thinking about their $\Sigma^c_3$ theories.